# Calculating a minimum number input without using sys module

Tags: python

Write a program in Python that reads a sequence of integer inputs (data) from the user and then prints the following results:

the total of all the inputs
the smallest of the inputs
the largest of the inputs
the number of even inputs
the number of odd inputs
the average of all of the inputs

You do not know how many numbers the user will want to type in, so you must ask her each time if she has another number to add to the sequence.

So far this is my code but I want to know if there's a way without using the sys module

```
import sys

# declare a variable largest which has smallest integer value
# -sys.maxsize gives the smallest integer value,you can also use any smallest value 
largest = -sys.maxsize
# declare a variable smallest, that is assigned with maximum integer value
smallest = sys.maxsize
# declare variables total to store the sum of all numbers
total = 0
# option variable is to store the user option  Y or N
option = 'y'
# declare variables to count odd, even and totalCount
evenCount = 0
oddCount = 0
totalCount = 0
print("This program will calculate statistics for your integer data.")

# run the loop when the user enters y or Y
while option == 'y' or option == 'Y':
    # take input of number
    number = int(input("Please type a number: "))
    # add the number to total
    total = total + number
    # increase totalCount
    totalCount = totalCount + 1
    # calculate smallest
    if number < smallest:
        smallest = number
        # calculate largest
    if number > largest:
        largest = number
    # calculate count of even and odd numbers
    if number % 2 == 0:
        evenCount = evenCount + 1
    else:
        oddCount = oddCount + 1
    option = input("Do you have another number to enter? ")

# calculate average
average = total / totalCount
# print the output
print("\nThe total of your numbers is:", total)
print("The smallest of your numbers is:", smallest)
print("The largest nof yout numbers is:", largest)
print("The number of even numbers is:", evenCount)
print("The number of odd numbers is:", oddCount)
print("The average of your numbers is:", average)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to "can it be done?" when it comes to programming is almost always "yes."

In this case, you can test if you're on the first loop iteration and set `smallest` and `largest` accordingly.

E.g.

```
option = 'y'
first_loop = True

while option.lower() == 'y':
  x = int(input("Please type a number: "))
  if first_loop:
    smallest = x
    first_loop = False
  elif x < smallest:
    smallest = x
  option = input("Do you have another number to enter? ")

print(f"Smallest number entered is {smallest}")
```

You might also collect the input numbers into a list.

```
option = 'y'
inputs = []

while option.lower() == 'y':
  x = int(input("Please type a number: "))
  inputs.append(x)
  option = input("Do you have another number to enter? ")
```

Now if you have all of the input numbers in `inputs`, then calculating a minimum and maximum is just `min(inputs)` and `max(inputs)`.

Comment: thanks for your advice. but in my class, we've not learned putting numbers in input so I don't think my professor would allow that.
Also, in your first response when I use "first_loop = true" the "true" part has red underline. Am I missing something? I'm a beginner at this. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Corrected capitalization. Thanks.

Comment: thanks for your help. I edited my original question and this is how my code looks now and it satisfies all the requirements for my assignment. but is there anything I can do to make it more neat or organized or short?

Comment: Please don't edit your question in a way that invalidates or makes answers redundant.

Comment: Also, I might suggest `evenCount = evenCount + 1` => `eventCount += 1`

Comment: You can say "thank you" on Stack Overflow by upvoting answers and/or marking them as accepted.

Comment: Ok sorry I'm new to this and it wouldn't allow me to post all my code in this comment. This is my first post but ill keep in mind next time. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Interesting approach, when I have problems like this I use `float('inf')` or `float('-inf')`. Can easily be worked into your approach.